# How do you create a button that will take you to a ViewController from a cell in tableview?

Tags: objective-c

I've written some code in a .m file and there is a separate .xib file. In the application the user should just press the arrow and end up on the next page. How would that be made?

Comment: where is the code

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question and I got the solution.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *strId = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strId];
    }
    UIButton *butArrow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    butArrow.frame = CGRectMake(200, 20, 100, 25);;
    [butArrow setTitle:@"Arrow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    butArrow.tag = indexPath.row;
    [butArrow addTarget:self action:@selector(actionNavigate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:butArrow];
    return cell;
}

//Button Action method
-(void)actionNavigate:(UIButton*)sender
{
   if (sender.tag == 0)  //Your particular or specific button tag
   {
     //Here Write the code for Navigating to next view controller
   }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `cell.accessoryView = butArrow`

Comment: Yeah but I gave very sample to the op.